# Integration with facebook using phonegap

Tags: javascript, facebook, phonegap-plugins

I am using sencha touch with phonegap. I am recently facing an issue with my app i.e. it needs integration with facebook. I am following the link

```
https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect
```

for connecting to facebook. I am doing everything as per tutorial but I found an error when i RUn the aap in XCode. The error is as follows.

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'Facebook.h' file not found.
```

I am stuck in this. Any idea about this?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

I am doing this change in my plist file ..

```
   <strong><strong>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.swenggco.facebook.myscheme</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb362599863837976</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</strong></strong>
```

this code is written before closing dict tag

Comment: In order to integrate facebook with your phonegap app, you need to setup the environment through these steps : https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect#add-the-facebook-ios-and-javascript-sdk . It looks like some file is missing so go over the setup steps and check if are doing everything right

Comment: I have done exactly the same .. But no success .. Is there any other way to do the same???

Comment: you can watch the video com facebook docs, it is easier to follow the steps. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

Comment: Also try cleaning your build by going into Product menu and clicking on Clean

Comment: I am sorry tried again the same .. But getting the error .. Semantic Issue Property 'CallbackId' not found on the object of type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand*'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have added the headers **(DeprecatedHeaders)** from the deprecated headers folder. Those can be found under **FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/DeprecatedHeaders**. I had a tough time making this work in my app. I had to attempt twice to see the output. Please try this step. Clean the build and run it.

Comment: I am sorry tried again the same .. But getting the error .. 
Semantic Issue Property 'CallbackId' not found on the object of type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand*'

Comment: Did you add a "*" under External hosts in the Cordova.plist?

Comment: Yes I did .. I have earlier mentioned dear that i have performed all the actions as per documentation but the error still persist :(

Comment: Ah.. ok. One thing you can try further is that adding the iOS folder under plugins folder in your project. If you did that and still the error persisted, let me know the error message again.. I know it could be little frustrating, but can't help it. I was scratching my head for a few days...

Comment: BROTHER done it again the ERROR is : Semantic Issue Property 'CallbackId' not found on the object of type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand*'

Comment: NOthing to hear from u yet ??

Comment: What version of Cordova are you using now?

Comment: Okay. So, you might want to give it a try with version Cordova-2.2.0 or higher. I have not exactly had this issue with this version. I googled a bit and found that it could be a reason. Just go for it and will see what happens..

Comment: Well have done it same again but this time another error .. /Users/Burhan/Desktop/facebookExample/facebookExample/facebookExample-Info.plist': The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted.

Comment: I think something something got wrong in plist file .. kindly post plist where I have to put the scheme ID + fb ID syntax .. I am a bit confuse about it ..

Comment: You see this error because you have made some unwanted changes in the plist file. Go to Resources folder --> Open your facebookExample-Info.plist file --> See any unwanted characters (like ~,"). If you find one, remove it right away. Clean the project and run it.

Comment: I have change my question and add the plist file view

Comment: Okay, so what you have to do is, just go to "Resources" folder (or Supporting files in some version). Click on your facebookExample-Info.plist file. Press Add button and then Enter "FacebookID" as key, String as type, and your Facebook ID (The one that you have got from Facebook developers website) as value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23275/discussion-between-geeniewanted-and-burhan-mughal)

Comment: Sure we should continue this in chat